# Removing namespace using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am generating XML file from MuleSoft and it producing empty tags like this. How to remove this using XSLT

```
<SerialNumber xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

I tried with XSLT code like,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*[local-name(.)='noNamespaceSchemaLocation']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its producing output like, `<SerialNumber nil="true"/>` I want to remove entire namespace, and output should look like `<SerialNumber/>`

How to achieve this using XSLT?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well we need to see a minimal input sample, to understand where the namespace comes from.

Comment: Your question is not clear: "*I want to remove entire namespace*" `xsi:nil="true"` is an attribute, not a namespace. Do you want to remove this specific attribute, or all attributes? -- P.S. Please pick either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both.

Comment: I want to remove entire xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" from node

Comment: That attribute's there for a reason, why is it important to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove that attribute then add `<xsl:template match="@xsi:nil" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

> I am generating XML file from MuleSoft and it producing empty tags
>   like this. How to remove this using XSLT
>
> ```
> <SerialNumber xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
> ```

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='xsi:nil')]"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<SerialNumber xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<SerialNumber/>
```

---

**One can even use the even shorter:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Dimitre